# Da um erro no "se" mas não diz qual erro é! visualg

Tags: visualg

```
algoritmo "tinder"

var

   l, m, i, b, c, s: logico

   pri, seg, ter: logico

   andressa, monica, leticia, eduarda, maria, ana, clarisse, joana: logico

inicio

      escreval ("----------------------------------")

      escreval ("        PAR PERFEITO              ")

      escreval ("----------------------------------")

      escreval ("Qual tipo de garota você procura? ")

      escreval ("Loira ou Morena? [L]/[M]")

      l <- verdadeiro

      leia(pri)

      escreval ("Inteligente ou Bonita? [I]/[B]")

      i <- verdadeiro

      leia(seg)

      escreval ("Carinhosa ou Safada? [C]/[S]")

      c <- verdadeiro

      leia(ter)

      andressa <- pri=="L" e seg=="I" e ter=="C"

      eduarda <- pri=="L" e seg=="B" e ter=="S"

      clarisse <- pri=="L" e seg=="I" e ter=="S"

      maria <- pri=="L" e seg=="B" e ter=="C"

      monica <- pri=="M" e seg=="B" e ter=="S"

      leticia <- pri=="M" e seg=="B" e ter=="C"

      ana <- pri=="M" e seg=="I" e ter=="C"

      joana <- pri=="M" e seg=="I" e ter=="S"

      se (andressa == verdadeiro), entao

         escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Andressa")

      fimse

      se (eduarda == verdadeiro), entao

         escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Eduarda")

      fimse

      se (clarisse == verdadeiro), entao

         escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Clarisse")

      fimse

      se (Maria == verdadeiro), entao

         escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Maria")

      fimse

      se (monica == verdadeiro), entao

         escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Mônica")

      fimse

      se (Leticia == verdadeiro), entao

         escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Letícia")

      fimse

      se (ana == verdadeiro), entao

         escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Ana")

      fimse

      se (joana == verdadeiro), entao

         escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Joana")

      fimse

fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
algoritmo "tinder"

var

   l, m, i, b, c, s: logico

   pri, seg, ter: logico

   andressa, monica, leticia, eduarda, maria, ana, clarisse, joana: logico

   formula: inteiro
inicio

  escreval ("----------------------------------")

  escreval ("        PAR PERFEITO              ")

  escreval ("----------------------------------")

  escreval ("Qual tipo de garota você procura? ")

  escreval ("Loira ou Morena? [L]/[M]")

  l <- verdadeiro

  leia(pri)

  escreval ("Inteligente ou Bonita? [I]/[B]")

  i <- verdadeiro

  leia(seg)

  escreval ("Carinhosa ou Safada? [C]/[S]")

  c <- verdadeiro

  leia(ter)

  formula <- 0

  se (pri = "L") entao
     formula <- formula + 1
  fimse

  se (pri = "M") entao
     formula <- formula + 2
  fimse

  se (seg = "I") entao
     formula <- formula + 8
  fimse

  se (seg = "B") entao
     formula <- formula + 16
  fimse

  se (ter = "C") entao
     formula <- formula + 32
  fimse

  se (ter = "S") entao
     formula <- formula + 64
  fimse


  se (formula = 41) entao
     andressa <- verdadeiro
  fimse
  se (formula = 71) entao
     eduarda <- verdadeiro
  fimse

  se (formula = 73) entao
     clarisse <- verdadeiro
  fimse

  se (formula = 49) entao
     maria <- verdadeiro
  fimse

  se (formula = 82) entao
     monica <- verdadeiro
  fimse

  se (formula = 50) entao
     leticia <- verdadeiro
  fimse

  se (formula = 42) entao
     ana <- verdadeiro
  fimse

  se (formula = 74) entao
     joana <- verdadeiro
  fimse

  se (andressa = verdadeiro) entao

     escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Andressa")

  fimse

  se (eduarda = verdadeiro) entao

     escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Eduarda")

  fimse

  se (clarisse = verdadeiro) entao

     escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Clarisse")

  fimse

  se (Maria = verdadeiro) entao

     escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Maria")

  fimse

  se (monica = verdadeiro) entao

     escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Mônica")

  fimse

  se (Leticia = verdadeiro) entao

     escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Letícia")

  fimse

  se (ana = verdadeiro) entao

     escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Ana")

  fimse

  se (joana = verdadeiro) entao

     escreva ("Seu par perfeito é Joana")

  fimse
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: ja coloquei com a virgula e sem .... da no mesmo !

Comment: qual a versão do seu visualg?

Comment: haha aqui não ou uma ou outra. Ninguém ganhou na loteria ainda kkkkk

Comment: a minha versão é a de 2015

Comment: consegui passar a parte do "se" o problema é que ele ta escrevendo para todas ... ou seja todas estão entrando nas situações ...

Comment: O visualg não está aceitando a forma como você está atribuindo a resposta no código para as meninas. Ex: andressa <- pri=="L" e seg=="I" e ter=="C"
Eu fiz uma resposta para a andressa virar true, mas quando ele passa por esse código na depuração, a andressa continua sendo 'false'
Acho que você vai ter que encontrar uma outra maneira

Comment: Eu fiz uma alteração bem radical no código, tenta ali pra ver se funciona.

Comment: Eu acho que esse visualg é todo bugado, pelo menos o que estou usando (3.0)
Na época eu usava o 2.0 e ele não era bugado assim.

Comment: como foi que vc fez essa alteração radical ? deu certo ?